# How to set the same image for iPhone Retina Display and iPad non Retina

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have developed an universal app and i import my graphics stuff. I came across with the following thought. If the icon that is referred to iPhone retina display and the file that is referred to iPad non retina display has the same size, is there any way not to import the same file with different names (icon@2x.png & icon~ipad.png) twice?

Comment: do one thing , don't include ipad non ratina icons , when user install app 1st time check device type , if that is ipad rename all @2x image from bundle to ~ipad. it just idea not sure about this

Comment: @TejasArdeshna you're not allowed to modify anything in your apple bundle, not even to rename a single file.

Comment: @hoya21 Are you using xcassets for image management?

Comment: @ChrisDroukas i am not using xcassets for button icons,tabbar items icons , etc. I am using xcassets only for App Icon and Launch images.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is such an icon size that would have same size for iPhone retina and iPad non retina device(Pardon me if I am incorrect). If you are talking about any normal image that you want same for iPhone retina and iPad non retina, and you want the app to automatically select the same image for both devices mentioned above then, no. You can manually do that though, which you probably already know.